# Necessary to use variable in postgres plpgsql function to get row count of previous query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

In plpgsql functions you can use `IF (FOUND)` to find how many results the previous query had. Is there an equivalent to get the number of rows from the previous query, something like `IF (ROW_COUNT > 5)`? Or do you always need to use a variable to store this value before checking it?

For example are these the only options?

```
-- option 1
select count(*) from mytable into thecount;
if (thecount > 5) ...

-- option 2
select * from mytable;
GET DIAGNOSTICS thecount = ROW_COUNT;
if (thecount > 5) ...
```

Have I missed any other options for getting row count of the previous query?

Which of the available options is the recommended one for getting the row count and why?

Comment: Option 2 will result in an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (select count(*) > 5 from mytable) then ...
if (select count(*) from mytable) > 5 then ...
```

or more funny

```
if 5 < count(*) from mytable then ...
```

`select * from mytable;` is illegal `plpgsql` statement so `ROW_COUNT` is not the option for this case.

Typically `ROW_COUNT` used to get the row count **processed** by previous statement (insert, update, delete).

---

**Update**

An if you don't need the exact count of rows but only want to check is it greater or less then some value, the more efficient way for such checks:

```
select count(*) > 5 from (select 1 from mytable limit 6) as t(x);
```

```
# create table mytable(id bigserial not null primary key, x numeric);
# insert into mytable(x) select random() from generate_series(1,10000000) as a;
# explain analyze select count(*) > 5 from mytable;
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                   │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Finalize Aggregate  (cost=116777.88..116777.89 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=348.815..348.815 rows=1 loops=1)                                  │
│   ->  Gather  (cost=116777.66..116777.87 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=348.713..368.395 rows=3 loops=1)                                        │
│         Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                    │
│         Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                   │
│         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=115777.66..115777.67 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=328.703..328.703 rows=1 loops=3)                       │
│               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..105361.13 rows=4166613 width=0) (actual time=0.013..211.543 rows=3333333 loops=3) │
│ Planning Time: 0.080 ms                                                                                                                       │
│ JIT:                                                                                                                                          │
│   Functions: 8                                                                                                                                │
│   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true                                                               │
│   Timing: Generation 1.422 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.484 ms, Emission 9.246 ms, Total 11.152 ms                                   │
│ Execution Time: 369.318 ms                                                                                                                    │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Time: 369,740 ms

# explain analyze select count(*) > 5 from (select 1 from mytable limit 6) as t(x);
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Aggregate  (cost=0.17..0.19 rows=1 width=1) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)                                  │
│   ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.10 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=6 loops=1)                                │
│         ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..163693.71 rows=9999871 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=6 loops=1) │
│ Planning Time: 0.104 ms                                                                                                │
│ Execution Time: 0.046 ms                                                                                               │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Time: 0,507 ms
```